# implementing async interface for in memory data list

Tags: c#, asynchronous, interface

I am currently changing a synchronous implementation to an asynchronous implementation. I hhave the following interface updated and defined:

```
public interface IMGP1DFC
{
    // get all
    Task<IEnumerable<MGP1DFC>> GetAllAsync();

    // get single
    Task<MGP1DFC> GetSingleAsync(int id);

    // add
    void Add(MGP1DFC mgp1dfc);

    // update
    void Update(MGP1DFC mgp1dfc);

    // delete
    void Delete(MGP1DFC mgp1dfc);

    // save
    Task SaveAsync();
}
```

I have a service implemented and defined using this interface that connects to a database like this:

```
public class MGP1DFCData : IMGP1DFC
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _applicationDbContext;
    //
    public MGP1DFCData(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext) {
        _applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
    }
    public void Add(MGP1DFC mgp1dfc)
    {
        _applicationDbContext.Add(mgp1dfc);
    }

    public void Delete(MGP1DFC mgp1dfc)
    {
        _applicationDbContext.Remove(mgp1dfc);
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<MGP1DFC>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await _applicationDbContext.MGP1DFC.OrderBy(x => x.ReceivedByDateTime).ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<MGP1DFC> GetSingleAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _applicationDbContext.MGP1DFC.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
    }

    public async Task SaveAsync()
    {
        await _applicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public void Update(MGP1DFC mgp1dfc)
    {
        _applicationDbContext.Update(mgp1dfc);
    }
}
```

No problems.

However, there was previously an in-memory service here:

```
public class MGP1DFCInMemory : IMGP1DFC
{

    List<MGP1DFC> MGP1DFCs;

    public MGP1DFCInMemory()
    {
        MGP1DFCs = new List<MGP1DFC> {
            new MGP1DFC { Id = 1, Name = "DS", Nino = "DS123123D", SentByName = "Bobbleton", SentByEmail = "Bobbleton@ds.com.uk.net", ReceivedByDateTime = DateTime.Now},
            new MGP1DFC { Id = 2, Name = "Kenneth", Nino = "FG123123D", SentByName = "Pattie", SentByEmail = "pattie@ds.com.uk.net", ReceivedByDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(6)},
            new MGP1DFC { Id = 3, Name = "Bob", Nino = "DS123123D", SentByName = "The Chieftain", SentByEmail = "cheiftain@ds.com.uk.net", ReceivedByDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(904)}
        };
    }

    public void Add(MGP1DFC MGP1DFC)
    {
        MGP1DFC.Id = MGP1DFCs.Max(index => index.Id) + 1;
        MGP1DFCs.Add(MGP1DFC);
    }

    public void Delete(MGP1DFC MGP1DFC)
    {
        MGP1DFCs.Remove(MGP1DFC);
    }

    public IEnumerable<MGP1DFC> GetAll()
    {
        return MGP1DFCs.OrderBy(x => x.ReceivedByDateTime);
    }

    public MGP1DFC GetSingle(int id)
    {
        return MGP1DFCs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }

    public MGP1DFC Update(MGP1DFC category)
    {
        MGP1DFC formToUpdate = MGP1DFCs.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Id == category.Id);
        formToUpdate.CompletedByDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        formToUpdate.CompletedByEmail = "ds@ds.com";
        formToUpdate.CompletedBy = "DS";
        return formToUpdate;
    }
}
```

Can I implement an async in-memory service?

e.g

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MGP1DFC>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await MGP1DFCs.OrderBy(x => x.ReceivedByDateTime).ToListAsync();
    }
```

Or is this a complete waste of time, trying!?

Comment: There is nothing asynchronous about an "in memory service" that only perform CPU-bound work.

Comment: there was previously a synchronous implementation in play. there were two services that implemented IMGP1DFC - one of which was in memory. i just wanted to keep the codebase the way it was in terms of the services available, but update the implementation (particularly for the db implementation)

Comment: This service doesn't seem to be anything more that a very thin repository over an EF context. That's actually an *anti-pattern* called the anemic repository. This code *prevents* the proper use of EF without adding any benefits. `Add` for example is the *EF-specific* way of adding detached objects. It's not an `INSERT` operation as it *doesn't* insert anything. Neither do `Update` or `Delete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is for this class to simply implement interface then you can write synchronous implementation of this interface by using `Task.FromResult`. This creates already finished task and all operations are done *synchronously*.

```
public Task<IEnumerable<MGP1DFC>> GetAllAsync()
{
    return Task.FromResult(MGP1DFCs);
}

public Task<MGP1DFC> GetSingleAsync(int id)
{
    return Task.FromResult(MGP1DFCs.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id));
}

public async Task SaveAsync()
{
    // Not much to do here...
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: In this case it would be better to return a `ValueTask` since there are no asynchronous operations involved

Comment: "You can implement asynchronous versions of these methods." You have provided *synchronous*, not *asynchronous* implementations of those methods.  Returning a `Task` doesn't make a method asynchronous.

Comment: @Servy That's why I wrote "They won't actually perform anything asynchronously obviously". They don't do anything asynchronous, but they implement asynchronous versions of methods from the interface.

Comment: guys - this is the kind of thing i'm looking for. i'm aware they won't actually work asynchronously, but i do want the implementations to adhere to the interface. i'm marking this as the answer. thanks for looking!

Comment: @FCin But you wrote the part that I quoted.  You specifically said that you can implement asynchronous versions of those methods and then *you didn't actually implement asynchronous versions of those methods*.  If you had said, "You can implement synchronous versions of those methods" then it would be correctly showing what your code is implementing (but not answering the question, which asks how to implement these methods *asynchronously*, not *synchronously*).

Comment: @dstewart101 Then you should change the question to say that you want to know how to write a synchronous method that returns a `Task`, rather than asking for an asynchronous implementation of these methods.

Comment: @Servy I didn't phrase it correctly. I think that it is pretty obvious what the point of this question is anyway. You have interface and you try to make it work with in-memory storage. I doubt that anyone would assume that anything asynchronous would happen with in-memory storage.

Comment: @FCin The operations can still be expensive and time consuming enough to need to be asynchronous.  There are all sorts of things an in memory data structure can be doing that would need to be asynchronous.  But at the very least, *don't falsely claim that the method is asynchronous when it's not*, that's just demonstrably false.  That you think that the method shouldn't be asynchronous (despite the question asking how to do it asynchronously) doesn't mean you should provide a synchronous implementation and falsely claim that it's asynchronous.

Comment: @Servy I don't think operations on 3 elements are expensive, but I'll rephrase my answer later, I don't have time right now.

Comment: @FCin The collection has however many items you add to it.  If you add 5 million items, there aren't just 3 items in there anymore.

Comment: @Servy This conversation gets more and more off topic. I'll rephrase my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing asynchronous about an "in memory service", assuming that it - as the name implies - only performs CPU-bound work on in-memory data.

Providing asynchronous wrappers for methods that are in fact synchronous is generally considered to be a code smell. Please refer to [@Stephen Cleary's blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html) for more information about this.

**Edit:** If the "in memory service" is only some kind of stub for a truly asynchronous service that communicates with a database and you simply want it to implement the same interface as the "real" service, you might use the `Task.FromResult` method to return completed tasks as suggested by @FCin. If the "in memory service" is something else, it doesn't make much sense for it to implement an "async" interface.

Comment: this was it... a solution for a stub type of thing, to "place-hold" for the real service is what i was looking for